# For a helm chart, what versions are available?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I  can specify a specific version of a chart by doing: `helm install --version <some_version> stable/<some_chart>`

But, how do I know which versions are available?

Comment: Originally asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031294/for-a-helm-chart-what-versions-are-available but I guess it belongs here instead.